# Instance Transform incorrect on update

Tags: wix, windows-installer, updates

I'm using instance transforms to install the same product multiple times on the same machine.
When starting the .msi installation file, I pass TRANSFORMS=":X" (and several other variables needed for the installation) on the command line, where X is the version of the Program to use.

In the Product.wxs file I then assign a new ProductCode using the InstanceTransforms tag, e.g.:

```
<Property Id="INSTANCEID" Value="Default"/>
<InstanceTransforms Property="INSTANCEID">
  <Instance Id="I1" ProductCode="$(guid.NewGuid())"/>
  <Instance Id="I2" ProductCode="$(guid.NewGuid())"/>
  <Instance Id="I4" ProductCode="$(guid.NewGuid())"/>
  <Instance Id="I3" ProductCode="$(guid.NewGuid())"/>
  <Instance Id="I5" ProductCode="$(guid.NewGuid())"/>
  <Instance Id="I6" ProductCode="$(guid.NewGuid())"/>
  <Instance Id="I7" ProductCode="$(guid.NewGuid())"/>
  <Instance Id="I8" ProductCode="$(guid.NewGuid())"/>
  <Instance Id="I9" ProductCode="$(guid.NewGuid())"/>
</InstanceTransforms>
```

Additionally, the UpgradeCode is added to the UpgradeTable in a custom action, the relevant code is:

```
Database db = session.Database;
session.Log("Get DB: {0}", db.FilePath ?? string.Empty);
string sqlInsertSring = db.Tables["Upgrade"].SqlInsertString + " TEMPORARY";
session.Log("DB Tables, querying with SQL: {0}", sqlInsertSring);
View view = db.OpenView(sqlInsertSring);
session.Log("OpenView, adding two new records to the UpgradeView.");
session.Log("Inserting line: {0}, null, {1}, null, 512, null, \"UPDATE\"",     
session["UpgradeCode"], session["ProductVersion"]);
view.Execute(new Record(new object[] { session["UpgradeCode"], null,  
session["ProductVersion"], null, 512, null, "UPDATE"}));
session.Log("Inserting line: {0}, {1}, null, null, null, 0, \"NEWERVERSIONINSTALLED\"", 
session["UpgradeCode"], session["ProductVersion"]);
view.Execute(new Record(new object[] { session["UpgradeCode"], 
session["ProductVersion"], null, null, 0, null, "NEWERVERSIONINSTALLED" }));
view.Close();
```

Ok, so far so good, this works for installations, allowing me to successfully install two instances of the same program. However, Updates don't seem to work. I can upgrade one of the instances, but when upgrading the second instance the transformation doesn't work correctly and the other instance is upgraded again.

Example: Two instances (I1 & I2). Upgrading I2 works fine. However, when I subsequently try to update I1, it just Updates I2 again (although the correct Transformation is passed).

The log of the MSI shows that the Transformation is first reverted to I1 (as it should), and then set back again to I2 (for reasons I can't fathom):

```
 - MSI (s) (B0:F8) [09:06:48:745]: Running product '{C33371A0-C32A-4120-BD8F-ACDC79E13458}' with elevated privileges: Product is assigned.
 - MSI (s) (B0:F8) [09:06:48:776]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying TRANSFORMS property. Its current value is ':I2'. Its new value: ':I1'.
 - MSI (s) (B0:F8) [09:06:48:823]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATADIR property. Its value is 
MSI (s) (B0:F8) [09:06:49:463]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENTDIRECTORY property. Its value is 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop'.
 - [Further arguments passed]
 - MSI (s) (B0:F8) [09:06:49:494]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTUILEVEL property. Its value is '2'.
 - MSI (s) (B0:F8) [09:06:49:572]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTPROCESSID property. Its value is '6424'.
 - MSI (s) (B0:F8) [09:06:49:587]: Machine policy value 'DisableAutomaticApplicationShutdown' is 0
 - MSI (s) (B0:F8) [09:06:49:634]: RESTART MANAGER: Disabled by MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL property; Windows Installer will use the built-in FilesInUse functionality.
 - MSI (s) (B0:F8) [09:06:49:681]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiSystemRebootPending property. Its value is '1'.
 - MSI (s) (B0:F8) [09:06:49:728]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying TRANSFORMS property. Its current value is ':I1'. Its new value: ':I2'.
 - MSI (s) (B0:F8) [09:06:49:821]: TRANSFORMS property is now: :I2
```

The last lines are significant: The TRANSFORMS property is set to I2 again, meaning that the installation will Update instance I2 instead of Instance I1.

Why could this be happening? The TRANSFORMS is passed correctly, I can't see why the property would be set back again.

(If more code or explenations are needed I'm happy to provide).

EDIT: BTW I'm using WiX toolset 3.7.

EDIT 2: For installation, I'm calling the .msi with following parameters:

```
MSINEWINSTANCE=1 TRANSFORMS=":I[N]" [Further parameters] (where N is the Instance)
```

For updates, I'm calling the .msi without MSINEWINSTANCE, starting directly with the TRANSFORMS part

As a dirty fix I'm now Uninstalling/Installing on update, which isn't exactly what I had planned.

Comment: I've provided a working solution below.  Property names and details are very important.

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention the [MSINEWINSTANCE property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so perhaps you aren't calling the installation correctly.  This property should be set to one.  For more details see: [Installing Multiple Instances with Instance Transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I've also explained the process on my blog: (Wow, was it really 8 years ago?)

[Multiple Instance MSI's and InstallShield 12](http://blog.iswix.com/2006/10/multiple-instance-msi-and-installshield.html)

Update:

I was able to correctly implement this using WiX and IsWiX.

Step 1: Use the IsWiX multiproject solution accelerator template to create an MSI/MSM project.

Step 2: Add a file to the merge module so that the installer has a component with a file as a keypath to install.  (This is required because a) you need to register at least one component to have a feature/product considered installed and b)  components with keypaths that are not files have to be mutated with different guids and conditional installation based on instance id.   To get around this and key it simple just create a component with a file as a keypath )

Step 3:  Add the following XML to the primary wxs file Product.wxs:

```
<SetProperty Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Before="AppSearch" Sequence="first">Not INSTALLLOCATION and Not Installed</SetProperty>
<Property Id="InstanceId" Value="0"/> 
<InstanceTransforms Property="InstanceId">
  <Instance Id="I1" ProductCode="*" UpgradeCode="{10E90C30-F117-4EE8-A084-25E4D0076CE4}" ProductName="ProductName-1" />
  <Instance Id="I2" ProductCode="*" UpgradeCode="{919F5399-4E7A-4D8A-9484-A85D0F5E2C77}" ProductName="ProductName-2" />
  <Instance Id="I3" ProductCode="*" UpgradeCode="{0BEAEF92-1821-4909-A83A-9B2AE2194AAC}" ProductName="ProductName-3" />
</InstanceTransforms>
```

This code mutates the installation directory on first install if a value wasn't passed at the command line and if the product wasn't previously installed (in which case directories are immutable)    I also use * to get a random ProductCode and pass in an UpgradeCode value since the project template uses MajorUpgrades out of the box and each instance is a unique product family for upgrade purposes.  Finally I transform ProductName to be unique in Add/Remove programs and to drive the installation location transformation.

Install the primary instance:

```
msiexec /I ProductName.msi
```

Install the secondary instance:

```
msiexec /I ProductName.msi MSINEWINSTANCE=1 TRANSFORMS=":I1"
msiexec /I ProductName.msi MSINEWINSTANCE=1 TRANSFORMS=":I2"
msiexec /I ProductName.msi MSINEWINSTANCE=1 TRANSFORMS=":I3"
```

Note the use of ":" in the TRANSFORMS property.  This specifies an embedded transform in the Storages table.

Both installations appear side by side in Program Files and Programs and Features.

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for your answer, I put the calling parameters of the installation as edit into my question (sorry that it took so long, I got the flue and only returned to work today).

Comment: I'm not really able to use the IsWix Project (business decision), would the normal Wix also put in a random GUID for a '*'? According to this site http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/generate_guids.html it will only do this for following elements: <Component>, <Package>, <Patch>,  <Product>

Comment: IsWiX merely authors valid WiX source. WiX still compiles it. I mentioned it because it was the starting point of an MSI that does major upgrades.  Yes, WiX accepts * for the GUID. The intellisense from the XSD says so and the build/test confirms.   This is a 100% confirmed working solution and fully applies to your question.

Comment: Ok, until now I'm doing a complicated custom action to get new GUIDs there, so this is already a big help! Will have to try out the solution and check if I can get it working like this, but in any case the bounty is already yours.

Comment: You should be able to copy and paste that block right in.  Be sure to use InstanceId not INSTANCEID as INSTANCEID throws an error at install time.

Comment: I guess I have an older Version (3.7), it gives me following error: The Instance/@ProductCode attribute's value, '*', is not a legal guid value...

Comment: I tested on the latest prod version (3.8) released last November.

Comment: Hey Christopher, updates still don't work, actually I've still got my original problem (Instance Transform is set to I2 on the second update, and then set back to I1 for unkown reasons, the log of the .msi looks the same as in my original post). However, with your tips (and an upgrade to WIX 3.8) I at least was able to throw out a lot of custom code (custom actions to generate GUIDs, custom action to try and write the update table, which is not working in any case...) so again, thanks a lot

Comment: Email me if you are interested in a screen sharing session to investigate.

Comment: We are having the exact same problem with TRANSFORMS. Did you make any progress you could share on this issue ? Thx.

Comment: stuck here also. Cannot see how to upgrade existing instances to a new product code. Any more light on the subject would be gratefully received

Comment: So im trying to set the transforms property to the existing instance manually in a custom action along with deleting the msinewinstance.
In the log i get:

"Determined that existing product (either this product or the product being upgraded with a patch) is installed per-machine."

But i just get the:

"Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel."